# Is there a way to pass the result of useSelector( ) as props to another component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-props

I have set the result of useSelector(example) to a const like so:

const variable = useSelector(example)

Is there a way to pass variable as props to another component from a functional parent component using hooks?  When I set this.state.data = this.props.data I get data: null.

```
<Component data={variable}/>
```

```
export default class Component extends React.Component {
  constructor(props)
     super(props)
         this.state = {
              data: '';
         }
   componentDidMount(){
        this.setState({
             data: <NEED HELP HERE>
          })
    }

}
```

Comment: The example you wrote is passing variable as a prop to the Component component.

Comment: What you did is what you want

Comment: @PeterLehnhardt Thank you for your quick response!  Maybe I should add more to my question.  In my Component, I have this.state.data = ' ' .  How do I pass variable to display in my class component?  It is giving me null.  I will add more to my question.

Comment: @windowsill Thank you for your quick response!  Maybe I should add more to my question.  In my Component, I have this.state.data = ' ' .  How do I pass variable to display in my class component?  It is giving me null.  I will add more to my question.

Comment: You can already see that props are exposed in your Component component as `props`. Simply write `this.props.data` to access your data prop.

Comment: @windowsill when i set this.state.data = this.props.data i get null

Comment: is `variable` null?

Comment: @windowsill. ah good catch. I checked my console logs for it in the parent component and it is null at first but then displays my array of objects later on.  maybe the props is passing it when it is null.  How do I fix this to pass when it is not null?

Comment: In your parent component you can use `{variable !== null ? <Component data={variable} /> : <p>Loading...</p>}` for example.

Comment: @PeterLehnhardt. thanks that worked! :)

Comment: @windowsill. Thanks also for your help! :)